# In doxygen, how do I hide a member function from "Public Member Functions," but still show it under "Member Function Doc."?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have some member functions that I don't want to show up at the top of the class page with all the brief descriptions, under "Public Member Functions." However, I still want the member function to show up under "Member Function Documentation." How do I do this?

I'm not talking about REPEAT_BRIEF, and I'm not talking about using cond/endcond to completely hide a member function from the documentation.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe, you would like a named [member group](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/grouping.html#memgroup). It will create another group of members, still displaying the brief, but not together with public member functions. See `Group2` in [this example](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/examples/memgrp/html/class_test.html).

Comment: Thanks Andre for that suggestion. I am aware of named member groups, and I am using them as well. However, I still need to be able to specifically hide a brief description but not the detailed description.